# SSIS getting wrong column type with OLEDB connector

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Halfway through a SSIS project certain table fields changed from `char(30)` to `nvarchar(30)`

However, when running the SSIS packages, an error stating `cannot convert from unicode to non-unicode` appears.
I am trying to transfer data  directly from a database source to its destination.

Both connections use the same database schema, so there should be no conversion.

When checking the external column data type it shows `D_STR`, which is not the case anymore.

I tried deleting both source and destination in hope that it would clean any sort of cached data, but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds to me like the metadata in your data flow task is cached and needs to be refreshed to reflect the new type.

Open the source, go to columns, and uncheck the column, then check the column. Click ok. The metadata should refresh now.

Comment: That was it. I could not find a way to reset the cached metadata in the flow, but that did the trick. It is quite bad to have to do that though, since one has to recreate the mappings in the destination :S

Comment: Think of each column as a pipe which data will flow through. At design time, you told ssis that you needed a pipe capable of letting 30 bytes flow through it. Then, at run time, you tried to cram 60 bytes through a 30 byte pipe. By unchecking the column, then rechecking, you forced ssis to review the data and replace the 30 with a 60 byte pipe.

Comment: I understand the need for the metadata. What i dont understand is the lack of a "refresh column metadata" button to force that "resize". Instead one has to redo the whole piping.

Comment: I agree, there should be a refresh button. However, you shouldn't have to redo the whole piping. After it recognizes the change, it should give you the "Restore Invalid Column References Editor". In your case, select all and use "Map using column name" then click apply.

Answer (score 0):

nvarchar and nchar are unicode.  Conversely, varchar and char are non-unicode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

As a result if you are moving data from one data type to another you will have to perform some additional transformation (CAST or CONVERT).  The other option is to look at your adapters such that char will use SSIS DataType of DT-STR and nvarchar will use SSIS DataType DT-WSTR

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx

Without knowing how your packages work I cannot be much more specific but hopefully this will get you going.

Comment: I was not converting data. The package was a simple "transfer from table A to table B" with the exact same columns on both tables. What happened was that, at a certain point in time, both tables changed that particular column, but SSIS did not seem to notice it